# The 'upto' method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm learning Ruby, and there has been a bit of talk about the `upto` method in the book from which I am learning. I'm confused. What exactly does it do?

**Example:**

```
grades = [88,99,73,56,87,64]
sum = 0
0.upto(grades.length - 1) do |loop_index|
    sum += grades[loop_index]
end
average = sum/grades.length
puts average
```

Comment: You may want to look for another book. In this case, this `upto` < `grades.length.times` < `grades.each` < `grades.inject(0, :+)`.

Comment: Hopefully your book isn't saying `upto` is an operator; it's a regular method. Edited your question accordingly.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune Lots of Ruby books are like that - they tell you exactly *what* Ruby has, but not *why* you'd use one way over another. :(

Comment: Oh. My. Gawd. This has *got* to be the crappiest Ruby code I have *ever* seen. Is this really code from a book?

Comment: Yes, it is from a book, Beginning Ruby on Rails by Steven Holzner

Comment: Since it's a book on Rails, then the easiest is simply `grades.sum`, is a fourth different way to do this, all of them better than that loop with `upto`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let's try an explanation:

You define an array

```
grades = [88,99,73,56,87,64]
```

and prepare a variable to store the sum:

```
sum = 0
```

`grades.length` is 6 (there are 6 elements in the array), `(grades.length - 1)` is 5.

with `0.upto(5)` you loop from 0 to 5, `loop_index` will be 0, then 1...

The first element of the array is `grades[0]` (the index in the array starts with 0).
That's why you have to subtract 1 from the number of elements.

```
0.upto(grades.length - 1) do |loop_index|
```

Add the loop_index's value to sum.

```
    sum += grades[loop_index]
end
```

Now you looped on each element and have the sum of all elements of the array.

You can calculate the average:

```
average = sum/grades.length
```

Now you write the result to stdout:

```
puts average
```

---

This was a *non-ruby-like* syntax. Ruby-like you would do it like this:

```
grades = [88,99,73,56,87,64]
sum = 0
grades.each do |value|
    sum += value
end
average = sum/grades.length
puts average
```

---

Addendum based on Marc-Andrés comment:

You may use also `inject` to avoid to define the initial sum:

```
grades = [88,99,73,56,87,64] 
sum = grades.inject do |sum, value|     
  sum + value 
end
average = sum / grades.length 
puts average
```

Or even shorter:

```
grades = [88,99,73,56,87,64] 
average = grades.inject(:+) / grades.length 
puts average
```

Comment: Good explanation. I would just add that `foo = start, enum.each{|i| foo = some_function(foo, i)}` is a pattern for which Rubyist can use `inject`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with inject. This method makes always knots in my brain ;)

Answer (score 9):

From http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_integer.html#upto:

> **upto**  `int.upto( anInteger ) {| i | block }`
>
> Iterates `block`, passing in integer values from `int` up to and
>   including `anInteger`.
>
> ```
> 5.upto(10) { |i| print i, " " }
> ```
>
> produces:
>
> ```
> 5 6 7 8 9 10
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Upto executes the block given once for each number from the original number "upto" the argument passed. For example:

```
1.upto(10) {|x| puts x}
```

will print out the numbers 1 through 10.

Answer (score 1):

It is just [another way to do a loop/iterator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Integer.html#method-i-upto) in Ruby. It says do this action *n* times based on i being the first number the the number in parens as the limit.

Answer (score 1):

My example would have been this:

```
1.upto(5)  { |i| puts "Countup: #{i}" }
```

So what you're actually doing here is saying, I want to count up from 1 to the number 5, that's specifically what this part is saying:

```
1.upto(5)
```

The latter part of code (a block) is just outputting the iteration of going through the count from 1 up to 5. This is the output you might expect to see:

```
    Countup: 1
    Countup: 2
    Countup: 3
    Countup: 4
    Countup: 5
```

**Note**: This can be written is another way if you're using multilines:

```
1.upto(5) do |i|
puts "Countup: #{i}"
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that looks more like Ruby to me is

```
require 'descriptive_statistics'

grades=[88,99,73,56,87,64]
sum = grades.sum
average = grades.mean
sd = grades.standard_deviation
```

Of course it depends what you're doing.